# Drawing bus route to Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, bus

I want to make a public transportation application for Android. First problem I'm facing is how to create a bus route and show it to users.

I have a list of bus stops coordinates. I understand, I have to generate encoded polyline which I did. Used this utility [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility.html). How can I only show the stops in this route, because I added way more points to the map than bus stops, because I want to follow the road correctly. If I add only bus stops, then it connects them directly which I do not want to achieve.

If anyone has done it or have knowledge to do it, please guide me to the right direction.

Regards,
evilone

Comment: Can't you just feed a list of coordinates using kml file to create a layer with bus stops as markers?  And you can just load different kml based on the route chosen.

Comment: @AR I want to for example show the user nearest bus stop and if user adds where he/she wants to go, then calculate best route match regarding to users location and final destination. Also I want to show all routes together in the map and also independently. Is this possible with .kml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a different list of overlayItems to indicate bus stops. It seems to me you did the most difficult part of your mapping related stuff in your app already, adding overlayItems is gonna be quite easy.

Stéphane